# Fastest way to curl 5,000+ urls and insert them in mysql database in php?

Tags: php, mysql, curl, pdo

i am using php curl to get data from an api

first url returns 50 urls and each of those 50 urls returns 500 results and a next url until there are no more results.

The code i am currently using is taking 5+ hours to complete as there are 2million+ records to insert into mysql from 5,000+ http requests.

currently i am using [ParallelCurl](https://github.com/petewarden/ParallelCurl) class to from petewarden -> https://github.com/petewarden/ParallelCurl

Here is my complete code:

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '3000M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 15000);
require_once('parallelcurl.php');
$host = "localhost";
$user = "user";
$pass = "pass";
$dbname = "db";
try {
# MySQL with PDO_MYSQL
$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}

$table="table";
$nextUrl = 0;

function httpGet($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$output=curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
return $output;
}

$html = httpGet("https://url1.com");
$arr = json_decode($html, true);
$curl_options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
);
$max_requests = 20;
$parallel_curl = new ParallelCurl($max_requests, $curl_options);
foreach ($arr['apiGroups'] as $key => $category) {

    $getUrl = $category['availableVariants']['get'];

        $parallel_curl->startRequest($getUrl, 'on_request_done');
            while ($nextUrl) {
                $parallel_curl->startRequest($nextUrl, 'on_request_done');
                }

    }
function placeholders($text, $count=0, $separator=","){
$result = array();
if($count > 0){
for($x=0; $x<$count; $x++){
$result[] = $text;
}
}
return implode($separator, $result);
}

// This function gets called back for each request that completes
function on_request_done($content, $url, $ch) {
global $DBH, $parallel_curl, $table, $nextUrl;

$arr = json_decode($content, true);

$j=0;
foreach ($arr['productInfoList'] as $key => $item) {

    $title = $item['productBaseInfo'];
    $url = $item['productUrl'];
    $img = $item['imageUrls']['275x275'];
    $price = $item['sellingPrice']['amount'];
    $pid = $item['productId'];

    $selarr[$j] = array('title' => $title, 'url' => $url, 'imgurl' => $img, 'price' => $price, 'productid' => $pid);
    $j++;
    }
        $datafields = array('title' => '', 'url' => '', 'imgurl' => '', 'price' => '', 'productid' => '' );

        $insert_values = array();
        foreach($selarr as $d){
        $question_marks[] = '('  . placeholders('?', sizeof($d)) . ')';
        $insert_values = array_merge($insert_values, array_values($d));
        }
        $DBH->beginTransaction(); // also helps speed up your inserts
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $table (" . implode(",", array_keys($datafields) ) . ") VALUES " . implode(',', $question_marks);
        $stmt = $DBH->prepare ($sql);
        try {
        $stmt->execute($insert_values);
        } catch (PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        $DBH->commit();


if($arr['nextUrl']) {
        $nextUrl = $arr['nextUrl'];
    }
else {
    $nextUrl = 0;
}
}

$parallel_curl->finishAllRequests();
?>
```

Comment: It's 100+ requests per second, ain't that fast? You need to find out the bottleneck but my guess is you need more bandwidth then.

Comment: try job server like `Gearman` http://gearman.org/

Comment: @DanFromGermanybut it is taking 5 hours+ to complete size of each request is 1-2mb

Comment: So to clarify, are you making 2million http requests, or 5000? if the former, then you are likely hitting your network limits (at around 110 requests per second).

Comment: @Steve 5000 http requests and inserting 2 million results in mysql

Comment: Ok, well then you are goinf to need to find out where the bottle neck is. Your code is not that easy to follow, but you could start by reducing the number of urls to a sample set (say 500 istead of 5000), then simply commenting out the database save, and see how long it takes. If the time is close to 30 mins (5hrs/10) then you know that the database isnt the bottleneck

Answer (score 0):

Spawn multiple instances of the same PHP script (run it from CLI) and use a centralized queue to manage the jobs not overlapping on urls...

I usually do this using redis as my queue, you can even think of using ready-made libraries like [this](https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque).

It should be quite easy to implement...

```
// pseudocode, in your jobs
$batch = $queue->getFirstAvailableBatchOfUrls();

// Do your stuff

// put again in the queue if errors occurs...
if($status == PROCESS_DONE_OK) {
   $batch->markAsDone()
} else {
   $batch->putAgainInQueue()
}
```

Comment: His code is already using curl_multi_exec, running the requests in parallel - likely the limit is his bandwidth

Comment: @Steve i have a dedicated server from hostgator

Comment: Having a dedicated server doesn't guarantee you a dedicated T3 connection